# How to disable price block from admin grid if this blocked in ACL

Tags: magento2, price, user-roles, acl, access

In this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/324446/92235, there is an excellent solution related to hiding the price from a specific user group. But this one does not hide the price from the grid, how can this be implemented?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**di.xml updated from previous question:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav">
        <plugin name="product_form_modifier" type="Mbs\HidePrice\Plugin\ProductAttributeModifier" />
    </type>
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns" type="Mbs\HidePrice\Ui\Component\Listing\ProductGridColumns" />
</config>
```

**preference as plugin is not possible on columns**

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\HidePrice\Ui\Component\Listing;

class ProductGridColumns extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\ColumnFactory $columnFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Attribute\RepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
        \Mbs\HidePrice\Model\AuthorisationReader $authorization,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        if (!$authorization->canShowPriceInBackend()) {
            unset($components['price']);
        }
        parent::__construct($context, $columnFactory, $attributeRepository, $components, $data);
    }
}
```

**I have done a small refactoring and now the authorisation is made in a separate model (see below):**

```
class AuthorisationReader
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface
     */
    private $authorization;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface $authorization
    ) {
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canShowPriceInBackend(): bool
    {
        return $this->authorization->isAllowed('Mbs_AdminScreen::Mbs_HidePrice::AccessPrice');
    }
}
```